# Receiving and filtering Ethernet frames via sk_buff

Tags: network-programming, linux-kernel, filtering

I'm trying to write kernel module that would catch Ethernet frames and make decision: 'accept' or 'drop' package (simple filtering). I used sk_buff and nf_hookfn with settings described here http://fcns.eu/2010/02/15/netfilter-hooks/.
 Unfortunately, my module works only with IPv4/6 packages. When I'm receiving raw Ethernet frame the callback function isn't fired.
Is it possible to make filter in kernel space that will be processing raw Eth. frames? Is there any other solution? I care about performance, I want to as fast as possible reject all unwanted frames before sending them to user space.
My linux: Ubuntu with kernel PREEMPT RT 3.6.6.

Answer (score 0):

Netfilters work on L3, the L2 alternative is called ebtables, which sits in ethernet bridge.

Take a look at how ebt_arp registers its match rules:

```
static struct xt_match ebt_arp_mt_reg __read_mostly = {
        .name           = "arp",
        .revision       = 0,
        .family         = NFPROTO_BRIDGE,
        .match          = ebt_arp_mt,
        .checkentry     = ebt_arp_mt_check,
        .matchsize      = sizeof(struct ebt_arp_info),
        .me             = THIS_MODULE,
};

static int __init ebt_arp_init(void)
{
        return xt_register_match(&ebt_arp_mt_reg);
}

static void __exit ebt_arp_fini(void)
{
        xt_unregister_match(&ebt_arp_mt_reg);
}

module_init(ebt_arp_init);
module_exit(ebt_arp_fini);
```